# when user click to button it should go to typing mode i.e. software keyboard should come out

Tags: react-native, keyboard, onpress

In react-native, when user click to button it should go to typing mode i.e. whenever user will click to the button the software keyboard should turn on and cursor should go to typing mode i.e cursor should point out the TextInput. 
that means i want the function which is opposite of keyboard.dismiss().

```
<Button>Typing mode </Button>
<TextInput/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by focusing on `TextInput` will automatically popup the hardware keyboard

Just give reference to your `TextInput`

```
<TextInput
    ref='myInput'
/>
```

and on click of button

```
this.refs.myInput.focus()
```